# Are Ninten and Ness related in anyway in the Mother series?

Tags: snes, earthbound

I wanted to know, is there was any relation to Ninten and Ness? Are they the same character or related in someway or is there no relation at all?

Answer (score 1):

I looked around on the internet for any evidence that would prove if they were related or not, and I could not find anything. There is nothing in any of the Mother games proving that they are related. There are plenty of theories trying to relate them, but none have been proven. It is safe to assume that they are not related.